# Hibernate many to many throw exception first time only

Tags: hibernate, exception, many-to-many

Hi I m new in hibernate , I did an application using many to many association , it throw an exception when execute the first time it said : Error executing DDL via JDBC Statement, Table 'gestion.cat_prod' doesn't exist. cat_prod joint table between categorie et production tables.
here my code:
Categorrie.java

```
package dao;

import java.util.Date;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

public class Categorie {

    private Long idCategorie;
    private String titre;
    private String description;
    private Date dateAjout;
    private Set<Produit> produits= new HashSet<Produit>();

    public Set<Produit> getProduits() {
        return produits;
    }
    public void setProduits(Set<Produit> produits) {
        this.produits = produits;
    }
    public Categorie() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public Categorie(Long idCategorie, String titre, String description, Date dateAjout) {
        super();
        this.idCategorie = idCategorie;
        this.titre = titre;
        this.description = description;
        this.dateAjout = dateAjout;

    }
    public Long getIdCategorie() {
        return idCategorie;
    }
    public void setIdCategorie(Long idCategorie) {
        this.idCategorie = idCategorie;
    }
    public String getTitre() {
        return titre;
    }
    public void setTitre(String titre) {
        this.titre = titre;
    }
    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }
    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }
    public Date getDateAjout() {
        return dateAjout;
    }
    public void setDateAjout(Date dateAjout) {
        this.dateAjout = dateAjout;
    }

}
```

Produit.java

```
package dao;

import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

public class Produit {

    private Long idProduit;
    private String nom;
    private String description;
    private Double prix;
    private Set <Categorie> categories=new HashSet();


        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub


    public Produit(String nom, String description, Double prix) {
        super();
        this.nom = nom;
        this.description = description;
        this.prix = prix;
    }

    public Produit() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public Set<Categorie> getCategories() {
        return categories;
    }

    public void setCategories(Set<Categorie> categories) {
        this.categories = categories;
    }

    public Long getIdProduit() {
        return idProduit;
    }
    public void setIdProduit(Long idProduit) {
        this.idProduit = idProduit;
    }
    public String getNom() {
        return nom;
    }
    public void setNom(String nom) {
        this.nom = nom;
    }
    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }
    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }
    public Double getPrix() {
        return prix;
    }
    public void setPrix(Double prix) {
        this.prix = prix;
    }


}
```

HibernateUtil.java

```
package dao;



import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;

public class HibernateUtil {
    private static final SessionFactory sessionFactory;
    static {
        try {
            // Create the SessionFactory from hibernate.cfg.xml
            sessionFactory = new Configuration().configure("hibernate.cfg.xml").buildSessionFactory();
        } catch (Throwable ex) {
            // Make sure you log the exception, as it might be swallowed
            System.err.println("Initial SessionFactory creation failed." + ex);
            throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
        }
    }

    public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        return sessionFactory;
    }
}
```

Categorie.hbm.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping  PUBLIC
       "-//Hibernate/Hibernate MApping DTD 3.0//EN"
       "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-mapping>
 <class name="dao.Categorie" table="CATEGORIE">
   <id name="idCategorie" column="ID_CATEGORIE">
    <generator class="native"></generator>
   </id>
   <property name="titre" column="TITRE"></property>
   <property name="description" column="DESCRIPTION"></property>
   <property name="dateAjout" column="DATE_AJOUT"></property>

   <set name="produits" table="CAT_PROD" >
      <key column="ID_CATEGORIE" ></key>
      <many-to-many  class="dao.Produit" column="ID_PRODUIT"></many-to-many>
   </set>
 </class>

</hibernate-mapping>
```

Produit.xbm.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping  PUBLIC
       "-//Hibernate/Hibernate MApping DTD 3.0//EN"
       "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-mapping>
 <class name="dao.Produit" table="PRODUIT">
   <id name="idProduit" column="ID_PRODUIT">
    <generator class="native"></generator>
   </id>
   <property name="nom" column="NOM"></property>
   <property name="description" column="DESCRIPTION"></property>
   <property name="prix" column="PRIX"></property>

   <set name="categories" table="CAT_PROD" >
   <key column="ID_PRODUIT"></key>
     <many-to-many column="ID_CATEGORIE" class="dao.Categorie" > </many-to-many>
   </set>
 </class>

</hibernate-mapping>
```

hibernate.cfg.xml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <!-- Database connection settings -->
        <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/gestion</property>
        <property name="connection.username">root</property>
        <property name="connection.password"></property>

        <!-- JDBC connection pool (use the built-in) -->
        <property name="connection.pool_size">1</property>

        <!-- SQL dialect -->
        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>

        <property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</property>

        <!-- Disable the second-level cache  -->
        <property name="cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider</property>

        <!-- Echo all executed SQL to stdout -->
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>

        <!-- Drop the existing tables and create new one -->
        <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>

        <!-- Mention here all the model classes along with their package name -->
        <mapping resource="dao/Produit.hbm.xml"/>
        <mapping resource="dao/Categorie.hbm.xml"/>


    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

this is logs :

```
bonjour
Oct 16, 2016 4:23:10 PM org.hibernate.Version logVersion
INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.2.3.Final}
Oct 16, 2016 4:23:10 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>
INFO: HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
Oct 16, 2016 4:23:10 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment buildBytecodeProvider
INFO: HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
Oct 16, 2016 4:23:10 PM org.hibernate.boot.jaxb.internal.stax.LocalXmlResourceResolver resolveEntity
WARN: HHH90000012: Recognized obsolete hibernate namespace http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration. Use namespace http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration instead.  Support for obsolete DTD/XSD namespaces may be removed at any time.
Oct 16, 2016 4:23:11 PM org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaReflectionManager <clinit>
INFO: HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.1.Final}
Oct 16, 2016 4:23:11 PM org.hibernate.boot.jaxb.internal.stax.LocalXmlResourceResolver resolveEntity
WARN: HHH90000012: Recognized obsolete hibernate namespace http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping. Use namespace http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping instead.  Support for obsolete DTD/XSD namespaces may be removed at any time.
Oct 16, 2016 4:23:12 PM org.hibernate.boot.jaxb.internal.stax.LocalXmlResourceResolver resolveEntity
WARN: HHH90000012: Recognized obsolete hibernate namespace http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping. Use namespace http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping instead.  Support for obsolete DTD/XSD namespaces may be removed at any time.
Oct 16, 2016 4:23:12 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl configure
WARN: HHH10001002: Using Hibernate built-in connection pool (not for production use!)
Oct 16, 2016 4:23:12 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001005: using driver [com.mysql.jdbc.Driver] at URL [jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/gestion]
Oct 16, 2016 4:23:12 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001001: Connection properties: {user=root, password=****}
Oct 16, 2016 4:23:12 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001003: Autocommit mode: false
Oct 16, 2016 4:23:12 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.PooledConnections <init>
INFO: HHH000115: Hibernate connection pool size: 1 (min=1)
Sun Oct 16 16:23:13 EDT 2016 WARN: Establishing SSL connection without server's identity verification is not recommended. According to MySQL 5.5.45+, 5.6.26+ and 5.7.6+ requirements SSL connection must be established by default if explicit option isn't set. For compliance with existing applications not using SSL the verifyServerCertificate property is set to 'false'. You need either to explicitly disable SSL by setting useSSL=false, or set useSSL=true and provide truststore for server certificate verification.
Oct 16, 2016 4:23:13 PM org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect <init>
INFO: HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
Hibernate: alter table CAT_PROD drop foreign key FK7s1f1o7oqk6wwmk7pytsxaqap
Oct 16, 2016 4:23:14 PM org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.DdlTransactionIsolatorNonJtaImpl getIsolatedConnection
INFO: HHH10001501: Connection obtained from JdbcConnectionAccess [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator$ConnectionProviderJdbcConnectionAccess@4b6166aa] for (non-JTA) DDL execution was not in auto-commit mode; the Connection 'local transaction' will be committed and the Connection will be set into auto-commit mode.
Oct 16, 2016 4:23:14 PM org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.ExceptionHandlerLoggedImpl handleException
WARN: GenerationTarget encountered exception accepting command : Error executing DDL via JDBC Statement
org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceException: Error executing DDL via JDBC Statement
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:67)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaDropperImpl.applySqlString(SchemaDropperImpl.java:374)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaDropperImpl.applySqlStrings(SchemaDropperImpl.java:359)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaDropperImpl.applyConstraintDropping(SchemaDropperImpl.java:331)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaDropperImpl.dropFromMetadata(SchemaDropperImpl.java:230)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaDropperImpl.performDrop(SchemaDropperImpl.java:154)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaDropperImpl.doDrop(SchemaDropperImpl.java:126)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaDropperImpl.doDrop(SchemaDropperImpl.java:112)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.performDatabaseAction(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:138)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.process(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:66)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:309)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:493)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:710)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:726)
    at dao.HibernateUtil.<clinit>(HibernateUtil.java:13)
    at uti.Services.addProduit(Services.java:12)
    at Test.main(Test.java:18)
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'gestion.cat_prod' doesn't exist
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:425)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:408)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:943)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3970)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3906)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2524)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2677)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2545)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2503)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeInternal(StatementImpl.java:839)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.execute(StatementImpl.java:739)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:54)
    ... 16 more

Hibernate: alter table CAT_PROD drop foreign key FK8820f0c5vl0w4qbdxro21vhsu
Oct 16, 2016 4:23:14 PM org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.ExceptionHandlerLoggedImpl handleException
WARN: GenerationTarget encountered exception accepting command : Error executing DDL via JDBC Statement
org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceException: Error executing DDL via JDBC Statement
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:67)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaDropperImpl.applySqlString(SchemaDropperImpl.java:374)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaDropperImpl.applySqlStrings(SchemaDropperImpl.java:359)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaDropperImpl.applyConstraintDropping(SchemaDropperImpl.java:331)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaDropperImpl.dropFromMetadata(SchemaDropperImpl.java:230)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaDropperImpl.performDrop(SchemaDropperImpl.java:154)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaDropperImpl.doDrop(SchemaDropperImpl.java:126)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaDropperImpl.doDrop(SchemaDropperImpl.java:112)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.performDatabaseAction(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:138)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.process(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:66)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:309)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:493)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:710)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:726)
    at dao.HibernateUtil.<clinit>(HibernateUtil.java:13)
    at uti.Services.addProduit(Services.java:12)
    at Test.main(Test.java:18)
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'gestion.cat_prod' doesn't exist
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:425)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:408)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:943)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3970)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3906)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2524)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2677)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2545)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2503)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeInternal(StatementImpl.java:839)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.execute(StatementImpl.java:739)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:54)
    ... 16 more

Hibernate: drop table if exists CAT_PROD
Hibernate: drop table if exists CATEGORIE
Hibernate: drop table if exists PRODUIT
Hibernate: create table CAT_PROD (ID_PRODUIT bigint not null, ID_CATEGORIE bigint not null, primary key (ID_CATEGORIE, ID_PRODUIT))
Oct 16, 2016 4:23:14 PM org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.DdlTransactionIsolatorNonJtaImpl getIsolatedConnection
INFO: HHH10001501: Connection obtained from JdbcConnectionAccess [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator$ConnectionProviderJdbcConnectionAccess@32fe9d0a] for (non-JTA) DDL execution was not in auto-commit mode; the Connection 'local transaction' will be committed and the Connection will be set into auto-commit mode.
Hibernate: create table CATEGORIE (ID_CATEGORIE bigint not null auto_increment, TITRE varchar(255), DESCRIPTION varchar(255), DATE_AJOUT datetime, primary key (ID_CATEGORIE))
Hibernate: create table PRODUIT (ID_PRODUIT bigint not null auto_increment, NOM varchar(255), DESCRIPTION varchar(255), PRIX double precision, primary key (ID_PRODUIT))
Hibernate: alter table CAT_PROD add constraint FK7s1f1o7oqk6wwmk7pytsxaqap foreign key (ID_CATEGORIE) references CATEGORIE (ID_CATEGORIE)
Hibernate: alter table CAT_PROD add constraint FK8820f0c5vl0w4qbdxro21vhsu foreign key (ID_PRODUIT) references PRODUIT (ID_PRODUIT)
Oct 16, 2016 4:23:14 PM org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl applyImportSources
INFO: HHH000476: Executing import script 'org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.ScriptSourceInputNonExistentImpl@32057e6'
Hibernate: insert into PRODUIT (NOM, DESCRIPTION, PRIX) values (?, ?, ?)
```

thanks for any help I m suck 2 days.

Comment: when I execute the application second time , that dont throw any exception. thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why you use configuration like below:

```
<property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>
```

This configuration indicates that Hibernate first drops the existing table, then creates a new table. It throws exception if a table doesn't exist. It seems you don't create cat_prod table yet. Here is why you just get this error first time only.

Solution, change the above configuration to like this:

```
<property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
```

Then Hibernate checks for the table. If table doesn’t exist then it creates a new table

Hope this help!